# Excel: Dynamic Range Date used in other fields: Sumproduct

Tags: excel, dynamic, sumproduct

I am using sumproduct formula to get the first four month, then the second four month, third four month of net sales until one month before today. This is my formula that I used:

`=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT($B3:$Y3*(COLUMN($B3:$Y3)>=AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($B3:$Y3)/($B3:$Y3<>0),1)+4*(COLUMNS(B3)-1))*(COLUMN($B3:$Y3)<AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($B3:$Y3)/($B3:$Y3<>0),1)+4*(COLUMNS(B3)))*($B$1:$Y$1<EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1)),0)`

However, I need to capture the same range as I have it for the net sales as for other measures like COGS in my example. I cannot use the formula above for the other measures like COGS as sometimes they are zero in the same range as in the Net Sales.But I need to capture the zeros here  as well.

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Nu6b.png)

[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5qu2.png)

Net Sales

| Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | June | July | Aug | Sept | Oct | Nov | Dec |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 4 |

```
---> 1st period= 14 2nd period= 10
```

COGS (follows the same date range as Net Sales)

| Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | June | July | Aug | Sept | Oct | Nov | Dec |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 4 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 4 |

---> 1st period= 2 2nd Period= 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leave the entire range check logic from the first formula and change just the value range, i.e first formula in my sample:

`=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT($A3:$L3*(COLUMN($A3:$L3)>=AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($A3:$L3)/($A3:$L3<>0),1)+4*(COLUMN(A3)-1))*(COLUMN($A3:$L3)<AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($A3:$L3)/($A3:$L3<>0),1)+4*(COLUMN(A3)))*($A$2:$L$2<EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1)),0)`

second formula for COGS:

`=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT($O3:$Z3*(COLUMN($A3:$L3)>=AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($A3:$L3)/($A3:$L3<>0),1)+4*(COLUMN(A3)-1))*(COLUMN($A3:$L3)<AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($A3:$L3)/($A3:$L3<>0),1)+4*(COLUMN(A3)))*($A$2:$L$2<EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1)),0)`

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. This is the solution I was looking for.